Gitlab GraphQL - get commits of a branch without merge requests
I am planning to use Gitlab GraphQL API, I'd like to get all the commits of a branch. In my project the commits are added directly to develop branch so there aren't merge requests.
I found this stackoverflow question but it queries merge requests' commits.
How to query history commits of certain branch with GraphQL
Do you know by any chance how to get commits of a branch in Gitlab GraphQL API?
Thanks, V.
